# require AMD modules in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm playing with TypeScript and GoogleMaps and I found some JS libraries that I don't know if I am using it in the right way.

Im trying to load and AMD module (infobubble) using require like the follow example:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import $ = require("jquery");
import Visor = require("./Visor");
import GoogleMapsLoader = require('google-maps');

//THIS IS IMPORTANT TO LOAD JS AMD LIBRARIES
declare var require: (moduleId: string) => any;
var InfoBubble: any = require("./libs/infobubble");
```

This piece of code works well but I'm not sure If it is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` statements do the same thing as an AMD require call if you are compiling with `--module amd` or `--module umd`. So, you should be able to simplify your code and just write:

```
import $ = require('jquery');
import Visor = require('./Visor');
import GoogleMapsLoader = require('google-maps');
import InfoBubble = require('./libs/infobubble');
```

(As a side-note, I would also recommend that instead of using a reference comment, you include your `typings.d.ts` file on the command-line when you run `tsc`, or you put it in the `files` array of `tsconfig.json`.

The reason for this is that reference comments affect the *entire* compilation environment, not just the environment of the file they’re in, which means if you change/remove this file you may accidentally break your build when other files indirectly rely on this comment.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: I tried to use `import InfoBubble = require('./libs/infobubble');` but I get the follow error:
 `error TS2307: Cannot find module './libs/infobubble'.`

Comment: You will need to create a corresponding d.ts file at `./libs/infobubble.d.ts` so TypeScript knows what is imported. It can be as simple as `declare var infobubble: any; export = infobubble;`, or you can actually model the library so you get accurate typing information.

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful :)